# What is the phrasal verb for working hard?

Tags: american-english, british-english, phrasal-verbs

I can't recall that phrasal verb and I'm upset.

It's like a **'s**** away'** phrasal verb.
Also, if I've got it right, it means to *work hard*, but it's not slave away.
Anyone?

Comment: [Work your socks off](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/work-your-socks-off)?

Answer (score 3):

It might possibly be *[slog away (at)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/slog-away)*

Comment: there you go man

Comment: I cross posted, though refreshed this page a few minutes ago!

Answer (score 1):

Slog

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/slog_1

e.g. *I had been slogging away at the computer all day without success.*

Comment: crossposted with @Henry [above](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/502394/what-is-the-phrasal-verb-for-working-hard/502398#502398), who answered first.